# Show Properties in html file after http request (Angular)

Tags: angular

I am trying to make display properties in my component file html after http request. I get the properties displayed in my views but i still get an undefined error in my console. Here is my code

Here is my component.ts file

```
 //// component.ts
    import { AdminService } from './../../../../core/services/admin.service';
    import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
    import { AppState } from 'src/app/core/store/state/app.state';
    import { Logout } from './../../../../core/store/actions/login/login.action';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { User } from 'src/app/core/models/user';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-main-menu',
        templateUrl: './main-menu.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./main-menu.component.scss']
     })

     export class MainMenuComponent implements OnInit {
     user: any;


    constructor(
    private adminService: AdminService,
    private store: Store<AppState>
    ) {

      this.adminService.getAuthAdmin().subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
      this.user = response.data;
     }
  );

   }

  ngOnInit() {

  }


  logout(){
    if (confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Logout?')) {
    this.store.dispatch(new Logout());
   }

 }

}
```

component.html file

```
   <div class="logged-user-info-w">
    <div class="logged-user-name">
      {{ user.full_name }}
    </div>
    <div class="logged-user-role">
      Administrator
    </div>
  </div>
```

The exact error I am getting is

```
 Cannot read property 'full_name' of undefined
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: can you try with <div class="logged-user-name" *ngIf="user"> {{ user.full_name }} </div>

Comment: @NoahLc that actually worked. Guess I did not think about doing it that way. Was looking for a way to load it in the .ts file before displaying it in the view but this works fine

Comment: Okay I will put it Like answer

Comment: or user?.full_name

Comment: @Alexander that's even better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check if the user has been loaded or not.
In your case, you can try with

```
<div class="logged-user-name" *ngIf="user"> 
    {{ user.full_name }} 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `?` after `user` like this

```
<div class="logged-user-name" *ngIf="user"> 
  {{ user?.full_name }} 
</div>
```